# Prove $E((X+Y)^p)\leq 2^p (E(X^p)+E(Y^p))$ for nonnegative random variables $X,Y$ and $p\ge0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

Suppose $X \geq 0$ and $Y \geq 0$ are random variables and that $p\geq 0$

1. Prove
   $$E((X+Y)^p)\leq 2^p (E(X^p)+E(Y^p))$$

   ## Proof

Since $(X+Y)^p \leq (2 \> \max\{X,Y\})^p=2^p \> \max \{X^p,Y^p\}\leq 2^p(X^p+Y^p)$ $ \implies E((X+Y)^p)\leq 2^p (E(X^p)+E(Y^p))$

2. If $p>1$ the factor $2^p$ may be replaced by $2^{p-1}$
3. If $0 \leq p \leq 1$ the factor $2^p$ can be replaced by $1$

Need help with part 2 and 3 any suggestions

Comment: 2. Use Jensen's inequality. 3. Use $(X+Y)^p\le X^p+Y^p$

Comment: How would you define the convex function. Im not seeing it @A.S.

Comment: 2. $f(x)=x^p$. Take $2^p$ over to the left to get $((X+Y)/2)^p$ to better see this.

Comment: @Josh if you figure it out please post. I am interested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^p$
By convexity $$f(\frac{X+Y}{2})\leq \frac{1}{2} f(X)+\frac{1}{2} f(Y) \implies \frac{(X+Y)^p}{2^p}\leq\frac{1}{2} X^p+\frac{1}{2}Y^p$$
The result follows.

Comment: For $p>1$, this is indeed true.

Answer (score 3):

If $p>1$, then by Holder inequality,
\begin{align*}
X+Y &\le (X^p+Y^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} 2^{1-\frac{1}{p}}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
(X+Y)^p \le 2^{p-1} (X^p+Y^p).
\end{align*}
For $0 \le p \le 1$, we note that
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{X}{X+Y} \right)^p + \left(\frac{Y}{X+Y} \right)^p \ge \frac{X}{X+Y}+ \frac{Y}{X+Y}=1,
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
(X+Y)^p \le X^p+Y^p.
\end{align*}